# Logging bugs directly from app to FogBugz

Tags: c#, wpf, bug-tracking, fogbugz

I have several WPF apps, and I want users to be able to log bugs *directly from these applications* into my FogBugz database. Is there any way this can be done? Also, how would I make it so that, when their case is resolved, the application tells them about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using the [FogBugz API](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/advanced/API.html), however you could do the same thing using the [ScoutSubmit](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/docs/60/topics/customers/BugzScout.html) mechanism FogBugz has which allowed apps to post crash data to FogBugz before the API existed.

Either way, if you have the user supply their email address, then your team that uses FogBugz can send them a note when they resolve the case.  If you use the API, then you could query the status of the case regularly to see if it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You could open a window with a WebBrowser WPF control displaying FogBugz.